# Determining entity denoted by name

Tags: c++, linkage

Declaration introduce name into declarative region. But when the entity denoted by this name does determined? At linking time or at compile time?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a=5;

int main()
{
    extern int a; //Is it true that entity will be determine at linkikng time
    printf("%d\n",a);
}
```

Comment: @NirMH I don't understand how and who does set that exactly this name will be denote exactly this entity?

Comment: Linker owns this task. `extern` is there to delay compiler memory allocation in the obj. the memory location will be found during link time

Comment: @NirMH And what about names which have no linkage? Does entity denoted by such names determined at compile time?

Comment: i assume linkage will fail. any `extern` will be temporary ignored during compile time, as `extern` is all about it...

Comment: @NirMH In my case? No, linkage will not fail. I still don't  understand when entity denoted by a specified name does determine?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52762/discussion-between-dmitry-fucintv-and-nirmh)